# URL rewrite from www to naked domain

Tags: azure, url-rewrite

We've got a Sitecore 9 Azure app service instance We've got redirects set up as follows:

```
<rule name="Root Hit Force HTTPS Redirection" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_METHOD}" pattern="GET" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This seems to be working as expected

- http://mydomain.co.uk gets redirected to https://mydomain.co.uk
- http://www.mydomain.co.uk/ gets redirected to https://www.mydomain.co.uk/

Next, what i want

- https://www.mydomain.co.uk/ should redirect to https://mydomain.co.uk/
- http://www.mydomain.co.uk/ should redirect to https://mydomain.co.uk/

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: So you want to redirect to https and strip www but only for root url (`/`)?

Comment: Hi Marek , thanks for your reply , apologies for not making it clear , not only root url(/), any url request , if it contains www,  I want to strip www and redirect to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a rule to remove `www` from a URL, copied from [this blog post](https://madskristensen.net/blog/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain).
It meets the requirements you've specified:

- It will handle both `http` and `https` (you have `https` redirect already in place);
- It applies not only for the root URL(`/`);
- It will also work with any hostanme, a hostname is not hardcoded;

Remove `www`:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This rule handles only the removal of `www`, so it comes as an addition to the `https` rule you have, not as a replacement.